# Joining table mysql -- without double iteration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

Let me start by saying this should be a relatively simple problem which is / was made unnecessary complicated by bad Database design (not by me) that said im also no expert in mysql.

Consider the following

**Table Schedule**

[image]

Note how the columns `homeID` and `visitorID` **contains the names of the teams and not the actual teamID's**

In a bid to fix this I  created a new table with columns containing `teamID` AND `teamName` as can be seen by below image.

**Table Teams**

[image]

**My Problem(s)**

**I must get the teamID from `table Teams` for BOTH home team AND away team**

So I created the `Teams` table and this simple script:

`SELECT schedule.*, teams.* 
FROM schedule 
JOIN teams ON schedule.homeID = teams.teamName OR schedule.visitorID = teams.teamName 
WHERE schedule.gameID = 411 
LIMIT 1 #added Limit1 else the code generates to rows`

**Output of mysql Script**

***Limit 1***

[image]

*Notice above how teamID is **only generated for 1 team** with `Limit 1`*

***No Limit Statement (Double Iteration)***

[image]

Notice above how teamID can get retrieved for BOTH teams. **Problem is its doing a double iteration.**

TLDR; The above presents the following problems

1. Firstly the script will generate two outputs one for home team and once for away team. As to be expected however I cant have that.
2. As a workaround to Problem number 1 -- I added `Limit 1` the problem I get with `Limit` though is that it only gives back a single `teamID` (as to be expected, I guess)

**Question**

How can I get BOTH teamID's from table teams with a single iteration? Hope this make sense....

**Extra**

A demo of application with hard coded team names looks like this (just to give an idea of what they are trying to achieve)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to join `teams` twice to `schedule`.

```
SELECT s.*,
       th.*,
       ta.*
       FROM schedule s
            INNER JOIN teams th
                       ON s.homeid = th.teamname
            INNER JOIN teams ta
                       ON s.visitorid = ta.teamname 
       WHERE s.gameid = 411;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input im gonna give it a quick test and report back

Comment: WORKS perfectly. Simple yet effective, Thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want to show both team in one row instead of two rows.
If yes, then you need to join the table `teams` twice.

Consider this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb5e61/1

This join will collect both teams into one row:

```
SELECT s.*,
       t1.teamId as homeId_teamId,
       t1.teamCode as homeId_teamCode,
       t1.teamName as homeId_teamName,
       t2.teamId as visitorId_teamId,
       t2.teamCode as visitorId_teamCode,
       t2.teamName as visitorId_teamName      
FROM Schedule s
JOIN Teams t1 ON s.homeId = t1.teamName
JOIN Teams t2 ON s.visitorId = t2.teamName;

| id | homeId | visitorId | homeId_teamId | homeId_teamCode | homeId_teamName | visitorId_teamId | visitorId_teamCode | visitorId_teamName |
|----|--------|-----------|---------------|-----------------|-----------------|------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 | Poland |  Colombia |             1 |              PL |          Poland |                2 |                 CO |           Colombia |
```

However you can also consider LEFT joins instead on INNER joins, which will work in a case where there is no relevant data in the TEAMS table:

```
SELECT s.*,
       t1.teamId as homeId_teamId,
       t1.teamCode as homeId_teamCode,
       t1.teamName as homeId_teamName,
       t2.teamId as visitorId_teamId,
       t2.teamCode as visitorId_teamCode,
       t2.teamName as visitorId_teamName      
FROM Schedule s
LEFT JOIN Teams t1 ON s.homeId = t1.teamName
LEFT JOIN Teams t2 ON s.visitorId = t2.teamName;

| id |   homeId | visitorId | homeId_teamId | homeId_teamCode | homeId_teamName | visitorId_teamId | visitorId_teamCode | visitorId_teamName |
|----|----------|-----------|---------------|-----------------|-----------------|------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |   Poland |  Colombia |             1 |              PL |          Poland |                2 |                 CO |           Colombia |
|  3 | Ya Majka |    Poland |        (null) |          (null) |          (null) |                1 |                 PL |             Poland |
|  2 | Ya Majka |   Rossija |        (null) |          (null) |          (null) |           (null) |             (null) |             (null) |
```

---

Here are the scripts that make up the tables from the examples

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule(
  id int,   homeId varchar(20),visitorId varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES
(1, 'Poland', 'Colombia' ),(2,'Ya Majka','Rossija'), 
(3,'Ya Majka','Poland');

CREATE TABLE Teams( 
  teamId int, teamCode varchar(10), teamName varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO Teams VALUES
(1, 'PL', 'Poland' ),(2,'CO','Colombia'),(3,'US','United States');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The Left Join advice is really great. Very good script!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery (two of them in the same query) to solve this:

```
select
  gameID, 
  weekNum,
  gameTimeEastern,
  (select teamName from teams where teamID = schedule.homeID) as homeName,
  homeScore,
  (select teamName from teams where teamID = schedule.visitorID) as visitorName,
  visitorScore from schedule;
```

This doesn't get all the columns from `schedule`, just an example to show how it works. If you need various queries (including `select *`, though this isn't a good practice except for testing), you could create a view based on a query like the above (with ALL columns from schedule, except homeID and visitorID that get replaced with sub-queries from the `teams` table). Then you can place queries against that view - and they will work like the original table where you had team names directly in it.